# NodeJs + Knex + MySql + WSL 2 getting disk to 100% running with a very slow performance

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, windows-10, wsl-2

I have a Razer Blade 15 laptop, running NodeJs with the knex library to access a MySql db by allocated in a WSL 2 VM.

This is the second time a come with the same issue, and the first one the only solution I found (by my own) is reinstalling Windows 10 to the fabric state.

The issue I have is that when I execute migrations (creating and altering db structure, like tables, indexes, etc), they run very slow. They used to execute in less than 1 minute, and now they take like 20 minutes, and I didn't change anything. The strange thing here is that when I execute them, my disk goes to 100% but running hyper slow, like you can see in the next image:

Disk at 100%, but System (which seems to represent the db calls) running at 1MB/s, when it can go up to 100MB/s without problems.
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMcpy.png)

All the other common apps runs OK, so the disk isn't the problem. I tried reinstalling mysql, reinstalling WSL, restoring PC to a previous date, and still have the same issue. The only solution I found the last time, after 1 week of trying, was to fully reinstall the OS.

I'm not using the mounted disk. Everything is running on the WSL2 VM.

Please, let me know if there's any information you need to help me, I'll send.

**UPDATE 21/10/20**
I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 in a new disk partition. To my surprise, I had the same problem than in Windows.

**Techical data requested:**
Disk: Liteon ca5-8d512 NvMe SSD
RAM: 16G
Processor: Intel Core i7-10750H, 6 cores, 12 threads

[Innodb Metrics][https://pastebin.com/Sx5FqiLi]

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
[image: See report]

IO tasks
[image: See report]

Tasks
[image: See report]

[https://pastebin.com/7X1TRrEw][Global Variables]

On Ubuntu 20.04, my process doesn't finish and shows this error:

```html
Error: Error while executing "/home/nicolas/SystemOne/Repositories/aspect/api/seeds/development/04_myanmar.js" seed: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Seeder._waterfallBatch (/home/nicolas/SystemOne/Repositories/aspect/api/node_modules/knex/lib/seed/Seeder.js:118:23)
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_MySQL.acquireConnection (/home/nicolas/SystemOne/Repositories/aspect/api/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:349:26)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:54:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:501:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

I also made a manual stress test, calling to INSERT several times, for inserting rows to a simple table, adding only values to 1 column. Each INSERT takes about 0.1 second to execute. Then, selecting all rows (like 730) takes 0.00036 seconds, so my conclusion here is that the big problem is the insertions or schema altering.
[image: See report]

Thank you :)

Comment: What is involved in a "migration"?  Perhaps `ALTER TABLE`?  How big is the table?  How complex is the ALTER?  Details, please.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck. I added almost all your proposals. My server is a localhost working on my dev laptop, so I'm not using MySql everytime. This is a process that I execute for creating a db from scratch and filling it with data. I run it in my other laptop (i5, 8gb RAM, SSD SATA) and it takes 1 minute and 30 seconds. In this one, it takes 30 minutes, if it finishes.

Let me know if you need more information. You can reach me on Skype, too: nsabaj@hotmail.com

Comment: @NicolasSabaj Did you post B) and F)?  Need the pastebin links to the data, please.  Thanks for data already posted.

Comment: @NicolasSabaj Your Skype has a tip for improving performance.